# Apache keeps resetting while testing on localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7, localhost

I'm getting errors while testing web pages on localhost.  I'm running Windows 7 64-bit.  I'm not using Wamp or Xampp.

This is what the error.log tells me (I've highlighted the errors in question):

[Sat Mar 06 05:10:55 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) PHP/5.2.13 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Sat Mar 06 05:10:55 2010] [notice] Server built: Sep 28 2009 22:41:08

[Sat Mar 06 05:10:55 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 6588

`httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.2.2 for ServerName`

`httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.2.2 for ServerName`

[Sat Mar 06 05:10:55 2010] [notice] Child 6588: Child process is running
[Sat Mar 06 05:10:55 2010] [notice] Child 6588: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sat Mar 06 05:10:55 2010] [notice] Child 6588: Starting 1000 worker threads.
[Sat Mar 06 05:10:55 2010] [notice] Child 6588: Starting thread to listen on port 80.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I may have fixed it.

In my `httpd.conf`  I added `192.168.2.2` for `ServerName`

Comment: @Scott -- duh :)